# How can I do access foreign key via arel_table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm studying Ruby on Rails.

I have some problems about foreign key.

I have two models book and author.

These models are below.

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :age, :address

  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author_id, :title, :cost

  belongs_to :author
end
```

I want to access author name from book table.

On console, I can access like this.

```
> book = Book.first
> book.author.name
```

But I want to access only column name like this.

```
 Book.where(rel_table[:name].eq("Sam"))
```

It doesn't work.

Because Book table doesn't have the column which is named by "name".

How can I do this?

I think just access foreign key value.

It can be possible simple way to do this.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Book.include(:author).where("authors.name = ?", 'sam')
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same answer as @Winfield but with only Rails syntax (which means this query would work with every kind of Database, depending on the selected adapter):

```
sam_books = Book.includes(:author).where(author: { name: "Sam" })
```

This query will return all Books having their author named "Sam".

And it's not even a arel_table!

---

I just saw that you are learning Rails. For the record, you could have done the same but in the reverse way:

```
Author.where(name: 'Sam').first.books 
# => Returns books of the author named "Sam"
```